# How to replace tabs with image in jtabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jtabbedpane

I want to use image in the place of tab. Want to modify tab of jtabbedpane. don'w want to use third party look and feel.

Sun provides this type of tabs

[image]

But i want it like

[image]

Is that possible?

Also want to now that how to create own look and feel like nimbus which is provided with java.

i have searched on google but didn't find any solution. There is only third party solution.

Comment: The phrase _modify tab of tabbed pane_ contradicts _don't want to use [another] look and feel_.

Comment: means don't want to use available look and feels like nimbus, quaqua etc. want to create my own.

Comment: Both nimbus and quaqua are open source, but it seems laborious; I guess I'd start with `BasicTabbedPaneUI`. Are you planing to do an entire L&F or just the `TabbedPaneUI`?

Comment: First i want to modify some components like JFrame, JInternal Frame, JTextField etc. then the entire L&F

Comment: Does [Synth Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html) help in this case? Apparently is "easy" to create your own L&F based on Synth API. Never did it on my own but don't think it would be as easy as they say. In any case you could give it a try if it fits your needs.

Comment: I want to modify JFrame's look. How it can be possible in synth L&F?